# C++ Sockets - Server doesn't accept multiple clients (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have working server and client code. The server and client can connect and chat with each other correctly. But when I open another client terminal, the client is says `Awaiting confirmation from the server` and nothing else. Although server and client #1 can still chat.

I searched on multi-threading but the examples or code snippets they show is advanced. Maybe a little explanation or an example will help a lot!

The code below is working. I have a working server but it only accepts one connection. How do I make the server to allow multiple connection? So that I can make the program look like a group chat.

client.cpp (when client #2 connects, the code freezes at line 40)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a;
    int client;
    int portNum = 1500;
    int bufsize = 1024;
    char* buffer = new char[bufsize];
    bool isExit = false;
    char* ip = "127.0.0.1";

    struct sockaddr_in direc;

    if ((client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        cout << "\nError creating socket..." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    cout << "\nSocket created successfully..." << endl;
    direc.sin_family = AF_INET;
    direc.sin_port = htons(portNum);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &direc.sin_addr);

    if (connect(client,(struct sockaddr *)&direc, sizeof(direc)) == 0)
        cout << "Connection to the server " << inet_ntoa(direc.sin_addr) << endl;

    cout << "Awaiting confirmation from the server..." << endl; //line 40
    recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);

    cout << "\n=> Enter # to terminate the connection\n" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Client: ";
        do {
            cin >> buffer;
            send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                send(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }
        } while (*buffer != 42);

        cout << "Server: ";
        do {
            recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            cout << buffer << " ";
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }

        } while (*buffer != 42);
        cout << endl;

    } while (!isExit);
    cout << "=> Connection terminated.\nGoodbye";

    close(client);
    return 0;
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int client, server;
    int bufsize = 1024;
    int portNum = 1500;
    bool isExit = false;
    char* buffer = new char[bufsize];

    struct sockaddr_in direc;
    socklen_t tamano;
    pid_t pid;

    if ((client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        cout << "\nError establishing socket..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\nSocket server has been created..." << endl;

    direc.sin_family = AF_INET;
    direc.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    direc.sin_port = htons(portNum);

    if ((bind(client, (struct sockaddr*)&direc,sizeof(direc))) < 0) {
        cout << "\nError binding connection..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    tamano = sizeof(direc);
    cout << "Looking for clients..." << endl;
    listen(client, 1);

    while ((server = accept(client,(struct sockaddr *)&direc,&tamano)) > 0) {
        strcpy(buffer, "Server connected...\n");
        send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
        cout << "Connected with the client, you are good to go..." << endl;
        cout << "Enter # to end the connection\n" << endl;

        cout << "Client: ";
        do {
            recv(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            cout << buffer << " ";
            if (*buffer == '#') {
                *buffer = '*';
                isExit = true;
            }
        } while (*buffer != '*');

        do {
            cout << "\nServer: ";
            do {
                cin >> buffer;
                send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                if (*buffer == '#') {
                    send(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                    *buffer = '*';
                    isExit = true;
                }
            } while (*buffer != '*');

            cout << "Client: ";
            do {
                recv(server, buffer, bufsize, 0);
                cout << buffer << " ";
                if (*buffer == '#') {
                    *buffer == '*';
                    isExit = true;
                }
            } while (*buffer != '*');
        } while (!isExit);

        cout << "\n=> Connection terminated... " << inet_ntoa(direc.sin_addr);
        close(server);
        cout << "\nGoodbye..." << endl;
        isExit = false;
    }

    close(client);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make the server accept multiple connection?

Thanks!

Comment: The server accepts new clients by executing `accept()`. So it will accept the second client as soon as you call it (assuming the second client is waiting). The trouble is your server code waits for the first connection to terminate before calling accept again. You need to look at `select()` or `pselect()` or `epoll()`. This will allow you to accept and talk to multiple sockets using a single thread. Alternatively you can spin up a thread for each connection after the select (but this only scales so far because threads are expensive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly support multiple connections you should fire up a new thread for each incoming connection. Each new connection is identified by its own unique socket descriptor returned by `accept()`. A simple example:

```
while ((accepted = accept(client,(struct sockaddr *)&direc,&tamano)) > 0) {
    /*Create the thread and pass the socket descriptor*/
    if( pthread_create(new_thread, &thread_attributes, &handle_tcp_connection, (void *)accepted) != 0){
      perror("create thread");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of issues: 1) C++ has its own threading model (you should probably use it). 2) Threads do not scale well (this may work for 10's (maybe 100 if you are lucky) connections. After that its not a good model to follow. Aim to use `select()` or one of its successors.

Comment: Let me disagree with the `select()` only solution. If scalability is the issue, the best approach is a thread pool utilizing threads and `select()`. But for a starting point I think that threads is the easiest solution, as `select()` makes the handling a little bit complicated.

Comment: @LokiAstari You can get much greater concurrency level out of a C++ threaded server than just a hundred.

Comment: @Manos: No problem with a thread pool and select that will work just fine. Preferably one of select() replacements though.

Comment: @PSkocik: A famous paper on the topic [A Design Framework for Highly Concurrent Systems](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/papers/events.pdf) I direct you to the throughput graphs in section two. Under ideal conditions (and I mean ideal) through put peaks at 100 usually much lower but that depends on the exact work load.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for the link. I heard about it but never the whole thing. Anyway, I can get concurrency of up about 600-700 out of the Poco's HTTPTimeServer example (with increased threading limits and queue sized ) with about 5,000-6,000 requests per second, repeatedly, without failed requests, tested with `ab`. If I go beyond that it will sometimes freeze for some reason and failures start showing up.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `select` or `poll` and a state machine pattern to do what you want to do. This means that you will need to process the data as it comes in from whichever client is sending it. Take a look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html#Server-Example) for a working example.